# Wrap markdown code blocks with prettyprint classes in Python

Tags: python, css, django, prettify

In python there is a markdown extension which highlights code which is codehilite. This extension wraps the snippets in codehilite classes. How can I get a function like this but to only put class='prettyprint' on every snippet without processing with codehilite.

Basically convert every `<pre></pre>` tag that markdown makes into `<pre class='prettyprint'></pre>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `str.replace()` or 're.subn()'? E.g.:

```
replaced = markup.replace('<pre>', '<pre class="prettyprint">')
```

or

```
replaced = re.subn('(<pre[^>]*)', '\\1 class="prettyprint"', markup)
```

Comment: If you meen Django template then that's not the problem. Just use `render_to_string()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut